# Loading modules in qooxdoo desktop (browser environment)

Tags: javascript, frameworks, qooxdoo

I'm struggling how to integrate client-side modules like - just as an example - [Apollo Client](http://dev.apollodata.com/core/)
into the qooxdoo-specific `generate.py` workflow so that they become available in the browser.

According to the [installation notes](https://github.com/apollostack/apollo-client#installing):

> To use this client in a web browser or mobile app, you'll need a build system capable of loading NPM packages on the client. Some common choices include Browserify, Webpack, and Meteor 1.3. [...]

Side note: I currently use Babel 6 to recursively transpile all my sources from a separate folder `source.es6/` into the "official" `source/` folder, which is then watched and processed by `generate.py`. Is it possible to use this somehow as a solution to my question?

OTOH, I would love to see at least some kind of integration with Webpack, Browserify or SystemJS.

Comment: Some chat regarding loaders/bundlers: https://gitter.im/qooxdoo/qooxdoo?at=57d17e7989655972304de46a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do the following. First, create a loadable package(s) from the Apollo Client and its dependencies, e.g. using Webpack. Then make sure these package(s) are loaded in your web page before you load your qooxdoo app. Then the Apollo API is available to your qooxdoo code.

If you choose to deploy the Apollo packages with `<script>` tags you can let `generate.py` do that by using the [`add-script`](http://www.qooxdoo.org/5.0.1/pages/tool/generator/generator_config_ref.html#add-script) config key.

I suggest you place the output of the Webpack run in your qooxdoo project's `resource` path and add [`@asset`](http://www.qooxdoo.org/5.0.1/pages/development/api_jsdoc_ref.html#asset) hints for those files in your main qooxdoo class. This will make sure they are copied into the `build` version of your app, and you can use the relative URI to these files, either in your `index.html` directly or in the `add-script` config settings.

I don't think your transpiling with Babel6 will help here. The Apollo code is already consumable and you woudn't want to disect it and make it part of your qooxdoo (es6) source tree, let alone its dependencies. I would rather treat it as a shrink-wrapped JS library as I described that is added like a resource.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasH. I do also appreciate your PR to the documentation  https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/pull/9181